# "I've brought my car to repair" Or "I am bringing my car for repair"?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, present-tense, present-continuous

Which one is more natural/common way to say:

1. I am bringing my car to repair
2. I am bringing my car for repairing
3. I have brought my car to repair
4. I have brought my car for repairing

After I entered a body repair store and say hi!

Comment: Hello best_of_man and welcome to ELL. On this site, we ask and answer questions about one specific aspect of English at a time. Here, you're asking both about the choice between *present continuous* and *past perfect*, AND about the choice between *"to" + infinitive* and *"for" + gerund*. Please choose *one aspect* to ask about. Also, to choose the tense, we need to know the context. Are you bringing your car in now? or in the future? or have you already brought your car in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all usable, the sentences that are with "repairing" would be usually if you are talking to the specific person that will repair your car.

If you use the sentences with "repair", it would be most suitable for telling a friend that you are going to the repair shop.

The best way to say this would be in the context of:

> I am taking my car to the repair shop.

Or if you're talking to somebody who's supposed to repair your car, say:

> I brought my car here to repair.

Answer (score 1):

The ones I would use are not in your list:

***I am bringing my car for repair***

***I have brought my car for repair***

Those I would consider to be the normal British idioms.